# Bash - setting a string variable and printf

Tags: bash, variables, printf

I am setting a variable as follows and when I print it out I get something unexpected.

```
sql="values ('$yy-$mm-$dd $time','$tz', $load)"
printf "%s\n" "$sql"
```

```
)alues ('2011-01-01 23:55:00','EST', 5081.2
)alues ('2011-01-01 23:55:00','EST', 475.8
)alues ('2011-01-01 23:55:00','EST', 1574.9
```

Somehow the closing parenthesis is at the beginning of the line?!
I check $load to make sure there is no newline character in it.

I am not sure what to try.

Comment: I suspect one of your variables ($load?) contains a line feed.

Comment: Your `load` variable is probably coming from a source that uses DOS/Windows line endings (which have a carriage return in addition to the linefeed that unix programs expect. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) Note that both carriage return and linefeed are nonprinting characters, so checking a variable for them is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks both! I do indeed have a \r in the $load variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command to check $load :

```
printf "%q\n" "$load"
```

You might see :

```
$'5081.2\r'
```

where `\r` is the problem.

**Update**

In your case, this check is even better :

```
printf "%q\n" "$sql"
```

Comment: Thanks .. yes I do have a "\r" in the $load variable!